# UICollectionView with two vertical sections per screen

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, calendar, paging

I need to display 2 vertical sections with headers in a collectionView on a vertical scrolling screen.

Two calendar months should be visible on the screen.
I need to scroll sections 2 per screen, as if the isPagingEnable property is enabled (maybe it should be enabled)

Comment: make two collectionviews?

Comment: [you meant something like this?](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/rkcalendar). Check more options [here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=calendar)